# Ho do I maintain session state in WCF Data Services?

Tags: wcf-data-services

I want to preserve some data through out the communications in a client independent manner (may not be related to business entities/data).  I am using WCF Data Services.  Any way to accomplish this?

thanks

Comment: Hi, have you found a solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the same as [WCF Data Services Sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8363363/wcf-data-services-sessions/8365963#8365963). WCF Data Services can indeed use asp.net session mechanisms: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wenlong/archive/2010/02/21/using-asp-net-sessions-from-wcf.aspx
Pay also attention that there are alternatives that perform beter, like AppFabric Cache.

Comment: **Not found** http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wenlong/archive/2010/02/21/using-asp-net-sessions-from-wcf.aspx