# WCF Data Services Sessions

Tags: c#, .net, wcf-data-services

does WCF Data Services support sessions ?
If so, Is there a good article explaining it ?

Comment: What would you need sessions for? Data Services isn't meant to preserve state across CRUD actions.

Comment: I need this to be able to send thousands of records across and then close the session and the session should save the records sent in a batch. I do that because by default, WCF Data Services doesn't support a lot of data being sent. see this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8304638/wcf-data-services-400-bad-request-when-saving-lots-of-changes

Answer (score 1):

Yes. [OData - WCF Data Services Best Practices from TechEd](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2010/06/11/odata-wcf-data-services-best-practices-from-teched.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Well, yes, you can effectively use the ASP.NET Session mechanisms. A very good article on that is this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wenlong/archive/2010/02/21/using-asp-net-sessions-from-wcf.aspx

Comment: I suppose you don't have access to OperationContextScope and AspNetCompatibility Mode. I am sorry then.